# My database is missing and disappeared after detaching it

Tags: sql-server

I have detached my database from SQL Server 2008 and unfortunately I do not know its path and by my connection string I extract its exact name and searched it but it is disappeared from my computer.

Is it possible?

I right clicked on my database and then `Tasks -> Detach -> ok` (nothing else)

Comment: Run a Command Prompt "as administrator" and run "dir \\*.mdf /s /a" - perhaps that will show you where it is.

Comment: You also may want to check the SQL Server error log - it should have details about the database that may help.  Also the "default trace" may have details.

Comment: It is so strange , I did your advice but I did not get answer , at least I am lucky enough due to have my data model in MVC 4 and I have to create my db again , I did not encounter this error before and I can not believe how after detach my db was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Short of checking the default path for your database you can do a search through Windows Explorer for `*.mdf`.

Default path for SQL Server is usually something like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\MSSQL__.MSSQLSERVER\Data` but that can be changed during installation.

Ensure you are searching for the files on the database server, whether it is a local instance or you are connecting to a remote server. [e.g. I can connect to MYSERVER1 default instance from DESKTOP1 but if I detached a database from MYSERVER1 I have to search MYSERVER1's local drives.]

Comment: I have done your suggestion but I could not find

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a backup of the database? If so start the process to restore it, the GUI under the 'files' page will show where the original files existed.